# Plot() does not use ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Hi guys I have a problem when I try to plot the history variable. Im computing neural network on a given dataset based on keras.
I used:

> plot(history)

In this case the plot is very ugly, I don't know why the `plot()` function doesn't use `ggplot2` in order to display better the plot. I already tried this (but I think this is automatic):

```
plot(history, method="ggplot2")
```

Of course I have `ggplot2` in Rstudio.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of `plot` says:

> Method to use for plotting. The default "auto" will use ggplot2 if
> available, and otherwise will use base graphics.

So if you have `ggplot2` loaded it will automatically plot in `ggplot` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(keras)
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
#> Loaded Tensorflow version 2.8.0
x_train <- mnist$train$x
y_train <- mnist$train$y
x_test <- mnist$test$x
y_test <- mnist$test$y
# reshape
x_train <- array_reshape(x_train, c(nrow(x_train), 784))
x_test <- array_reshape(x_test, c(nrow(x_test), 784))
# rescale
x_train <- x_train / 255
x_test <- x_test / 255
y_train <- to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test <- to_categorical(y_test, 10)
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(784)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax')

model %>% compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train, 
  epochs = 30, batch_size = 128, 
  validation_split = 0.2
)

plot(history)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

So I would suggest checking if you have `ggplot2` loaded, otherwise, you get this (Please in my case it is loaded):

```r
library(keras)
#> Warning: package 'keras' was built under R version 4.1.2
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
#> Loaded Tensorflow version 2.8.0
x_train <- mnist$train$x
y_train <- mnist$train$y
x_test <- mnist$test$x
y_test <- mnist$test$y
# reshape
x_train <- array_reshape(x_train, c(nrow(x_train), 784))
x_test <- array_reshape(x_test, c(nrow(x_test), 784))
# rescale
x_train <- x_train / 255
x_test <- x_test / 255
y_train <- to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test <- to_categorical(y_test, 10)
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(784)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax')

model %>% compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train, 
  epochs = 30, batch_size = 128, 
  validation_split = 0.2
)

plot(history, method = "base")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>